# ethernet wall socket - are they all the same?

Tags: networking, ethernet, home-networking, gigabit-ethernet

so the house already has some ethernet wall sockets which I believe were installed when 100Mbps was more common. The cable current in used seemed to indicate that's it's not gigabit capable. I want to rewire it to CAT6. Do I need to change the sockets as well?

I looked at eBay at several wall sockets supposedly designed for CAT6 but I can't see any difference to my untrained eye.

Thank you for the help. :)

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/663732/can-i-use-cat5e-jacks-with-cat6-cable

Comment: Thats odd, since regular old Cat5 will carry gigabit without difficulty, but cat 4 will not carry 100megabit, so it is unclear to me how it can be 100BaseT capable, but ot 1000BaseT. Anyway, to directly answer your question, if the sockets have 8 pins, then you can reuse them. If you are goign to go to the trouble of rewiring however, you might as well replace them.

Comment: Unless you have a lot of experience with cable installation and a very, very expensive cable tester, Category-6 cable will be a waste of money since you couldn't install it to pass the Category-6 test suite. Category-5E will run gigabit, if properly installed. A cable system has the rating of the lowest component (patch cord, terminations, horizontal and vertical cable, patch panels, etc.) in the system, so you will need to use components of the same rating, or you will be wasting money.

Answer (score -1):

Based on experience, you're unlike to find any trouble using existing sockets and maybe some of the cables as well (as long as they have all 4 pairs instead of just 2). I have used many old dodgy cables in my GbE setup and very rarely had problems (at short distances at least).